# How to fill canvas and add text

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to fill my canvas with a image (base64-string) and than add a text into the canvas.

Initial idea (javascript browser application): I want to set the base64-string `txtb64` (Image) as background image of the canvas and than add the text over it.

```
downloadtext: function() {
  var sign = this.getView().byId("SigId");
  var txtb64 = signpad.getSignAsJpeg();

  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = txtb64;
  image.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Ready!");
  });

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  ctx.fillText('My random text', 0, 0);

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

  var image = new Image();
  var element = document.createElement('a');

  image.src = dataURL;

  element.setAttribute('href', image.src);
  element.setAttribute('download', 'image');
  element.style.display = 'none';

  element.click();
},
```

The problem is I always get a black rectangle as output.
What is wrong with my code, because i can see no error.

Comment: Does `getSignAsJpeg` return data starting with `data:image/[jpeg];base64,` or is it just the base64 data?

Comment: The return data is starting with ```data:image/[jpeg];base64,```

Comment: @MattEllen do you know what's the problem here?

Comment: What happens if you put everything below the declaration of the "load" event handler, into the event handler function?

Comment: then i get the following error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'```

Comment: Sounds like there's an issue with the data coming from `getSignAsJpeg`. What happens if you use a known good jpeg, i.e `image.src=[path to jpeg]`?

Comment: There i am getting the same result. Just a black rectangle as output. :(

Comment: the exact result of ```getSignAsJpeg``` is ```txtb64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA..........```

Comment: So with a known good jpeg, you're not getting the `Uncaught TypeError`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192763/discussion-between-alfons-alpi-and-matt-ellen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should put the code needed to download the new image inside the "load" event handler of the image you create. This is needed because the load event could trigger after the code beneath it runs, resulting in an empty image being put onto the canvas.

Also you declare `var image = new Image();` twice, which could also be causing issues. Calling one `image1` and the other `image2` will prevent that.

**WARNING** Running this snippet triggers a download request.

```js
var data = "data:image/png;base64,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";

var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();

img.src = data;

img.addEventListener('load', e =>
{
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  
  ctx.fillText('My random text', 100, 100);
  
  var dataURL = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

  var image = new Image();
  var element = document.createElement('a');

  image.src = dataURL;
  
  element.setAttribute('href', image.src);
  element.setAttribute('download', 'image');
  
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  
  element.click();
});
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="can"></canvas>
```